# How to Insert Existing image that is showing in the page?

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I've been doing a simple add-to-cart, and somehow I figure out to insert the information from my table **products** to my table **cart**.

So when I render my details.php that is currently grabbing the information from **products** table and then click add-to-cart, my **cart** table grabs the information from details.php. and store it my database.

[image: This is the details.php]

[image: Backend Image]

The only problem I'm encountering is, I can't save the image to the **cart** table.

I want the image to save in the **cart** table and render it if I want to.

details.php

```
<?php

session_start();


require('../backend/clientbackend.php');
$fetch = singleInfo();
$current_price = $fetch['price'];




?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
    <title>E-Commerce</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="left">
            <h4 class="navbar-header"> <a href="../index.php">Branding</a> </h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Shop</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <button class="loginButton">Login</button>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <article>
        <form method="post" class="product-description">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="left-title" name="name"> <?php echo $fetch['name']; ?> </div>
                <div class="left-info">
                    <p class="left-description"> <?php echo $fetch['desc']; ?> </p>
                    <span class="price" name="price"> $ <strong> <?php echo $fetch['price']; ?></strong> </span>

                </div>
                <div class="left-increment">
                    <div class="addition">+</div>
                    <input type="number" class="current_value" value="1" min="1">
                    <div class="subtraction">-</div>
                    <button class="gotoCart" name="addcart" type="submit"> Add To Cart </button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="right-image">
                    <img name="image" src="<?php echo '../uploads/' . $fetch['image']; ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </article>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer-container">
            <div class="box1">
                <h3>Ecommerce Branding</h3>
                <span>School Activity</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <h3>Colegio De San Lorenzo
                </h3>
                <span>Congressional Ave, Project 8, Quezon City, Metro Manila</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <h3>Emman Cruz</h3>
                <span> zurcemozz@gmail.com</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script>
        const addBtn = document.querySelector('.addition');
        const subBtn = document.querySelector('.subtraction');
        let currentValue = document.querySelector('.current_value');


        let stock = 1;


        addBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            stock = stock + 1
            currentValue.value = stock;
            console.log(currentValue.value);


        })
        subBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

            if (stock <= 0) {
                stock = 0;
            } else {
                stock = stock - 1
                currentValue.value = stock;
                console.log(currentValue.value);
            }

        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

clientbackend.php

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
function singleInfo()
{
    $con = connection();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `id`='$id' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $fetch;
}



if (isset($_POST['addcart'])) {
    $con = connection();
    $fetch = singleInfo();
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $price = $fetch['price'];
    $image = $fetch['image'];

    //echo "<img src='../uploads/$image' alt='img'>";


    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `cart`(`name`, `price`) VALUES ('$name','$price')");

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

so in worst case, should I use the join table method in php? or is there anyway that i can immediatley grab the image...store it to my image-folder and database, and then render it?

ps. sorry for adding a lot if pictures,

Comment: you need to normalise the tables first and foremost, i'd say separate the the shopping cart table and the items in the shopping cart in another table, and have reference keys in them. right now it's just one big shopping cart for all the people logging into your system. and this isn't new you could just google a simple db design for a shopping cart, then tailor fit it (the fields) into your system.

Comment: so i need to learn the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

you need to save product_id in your Cart table and then you can join from cart to product table like this

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cart left join products on cart.product_id = product.id' ";
```

your image should save on product table.

if you want to store image in card table , you can send product_id in ajax request and then get product detail from product table like this and save image to card table

```
select * from product where id = $_POST['product_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the image in the database, instead save the URL to the image.  That is just a VARCHAR.